# How can I call a function within the main function - supabase?

Tags: postgresql, supabase, supabase-js

i have this function when a user signs up I insert some data to the profiles table,after that,
I want to generate a code digit and insert it into the paring_codes tablebut I got this error in LOGs

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_unique_code(user_id UUID)
RETURNS VARCHAR AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN md5(user_id::TEXT || RANDOM()::TEXT);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;`



-- Trigger Function to Handle New User Sign Up
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION handle_new_user()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO public.profiles (id, username)
  VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.raw_user_meta_data->>'username');

  INSERT INTO public.pairing_codes (code, user_id)
  VALUES (generate_unique_code(NEW.id), NEW.id);

  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

> "error": "failed to close prepared statement: ERROR: current
> transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction
> block (SQLSTATE 25P02): ERROR: function generate_unique_code(uuid)
> does not exist (SQLSTATE 42883)"

Comment: I think there may be a schema reference issue here -- I'd recommend updating the functions to reference the specific schema where you'd like them defined: `public.generate_unique_code()` and `public.handle_new_user()`.

Comment: @joe yes, i solved it by using public.myFunctions()

Comment: Awesome! Go ahead and accept the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend updating the functions to reference the specific schema where you'd like them defined: `public.generate_unique_code()` and `public.handle_new_user()`.

[Schema Docs](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/tables#schemas)